# How to know what JavaScript or jquery use in the some specific part of the website or html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am watching invisionapp website some time ago and i like his website animation, now i want to apply that animation in my html page so, that i am try to find how it's work.

But i am not able to find out how that animation work and which javascripts used by devloper for apply that html page svg animation.(I am asking about invisionapp's website svg animation not invisionapp animation). i am also try by saving web page in local but not work.

if any one know how all that animation work or what js they use then help me to understand that animation.[image: Here is the image for what i say[][1]]
[Here is the link for invisionapp website](https://www.invisionapp.com/feature/freehand)

Answer (score 1):

You can use your browser's developer tools to dig into the scripts loaded on the page.
Here is what i could gather:

Graphics/animations made in Adobe AfterEffects, exported to JSON with https://aescripts.com/bodymovin/

Greensock Animation Platform (GSAP) with plugins:

- Animation
- ScrollMagic
- EasePack
- TimelineLite
- TweenLite
- CSSPlugin
- AttrPlugin

Also jQuery

Then the code controlling all this seems to be in https://www.invisionapp.com/subsystems/landing/assets/js/freehand.min.js

Answer (score 1):

The Developer tools in the web browsers have a 'Performance', you can use it record the events happening the page and try to figure out what script is triggering the event/animation.

It will be still be difficult, because scripts are probably minified and obfuscated.